# Blueimp, backload and file extesion restriction

Tags: asp.net, blueimp, backload

I'm using Blueimp and Backload to handle file uploads in my asp.net application. I know how to restrict file extensions by doing something like:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/png" multiple>
```

But I also need to validate the file extension in the server side before writing it to disc.

Any tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, this will be implemented in the coming release:
https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/wiki/Release-notes#1940-current-dev

Meanwhile use the workaround described here:
https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/issues/32

Comment: Link is broken - looks like Backload removed its issues entirely from github. I'm guessing it was an extension or something like that?